# Ada: Incompatible alignment warning issued when specifying an address clause

Tags: ada

Is there an ideal way to avoid compile-time warnings about incompatible alignment raised when using the `import` clause on architectures with strict alignment requirements?

This behavior is described in the GCC manual [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Address-Clauses.html). I'm compiling with `riscv64-elf-gnat`. All warnings are enabled, and warnings treated as errors. I understand that I can suppress this particular warning. Is there an ideal way to handle this scenario in code?

This warning seems rather arbitrary. It doesn't seem to be possible to handle this scenario within the exception handling block of the function itself.
Any help here would be appreciated.

For example, the code below:

```
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   --  Read_Unsigned_8
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   function Read_Unsigned_8 (
     Addr : System.Address
   ) return Unsigned_8 is
      Data : Unsigned_8
      with Import,
        Address => Addr;
   begin
      return Data;
   end Read_Unsigned_8;
```

Raises this warning:

```
mmio.adb:23:09: warning: pragma Restrictions (No_Exception_Propagation) in effect
mmio.adb:23:09: warning: "Program_Error" may call Last_Chance_Handler
mmio.adb:23:09: warning: address value may be incompatible with alignment of object
```

Comment: There are other attributes : if Address is 32-bit aligned, perhaps specifying Size=32 for Data (even though it is a byte) will keep it aligned to Addresses? This is merely a suggestion : I don't know how Risc-V handles byte addressing.

Comment: @BrianDrummond `Address` will have 32-bit alignment (or even 64-bit?), but what counts is its _value_. If `Data` had 16-bit alignment, the  value would need to be even, etc.

Comment: @Simon : yes I was unclear, I meant the "alignment" of its value ... can it point to every byte or only every fourth byte? Some RISCs had the latter property, but apparently not RISC-V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With arm-eabi, you can make this over-enthusiastic (not to say *wrong*) warning go away by specifying the alignment:

```
   Data : Unsigned_8
     with
       Import,
       Address   => Addr,
       Alignment => 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Simon. This resolves the issue. It does seem a little obvious now that I see it. One potential issue is that this solution really only seems to work where an alignment of 1 is ideal.

Comment: What’s annoying is that `-gnatR2` shows that GNAT knows perfectly well what the alignment is!